# How can I focus on an input tag that is inside a div tag and is not showing up?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So I've been learning about `BeautifulSoup` and I tried to make a little script that is looking to the Nike web page to check if a specific size of a pair of shoes is available.

The problem I've encountered is that I have not been able to focus on a specific tag that is containing the value which is displaying the availability of the specific size. Here is my code (it's really bad and is not complete):

```
import requests, bs4

print("Looking it up...")

res = requests.get('https://www.nike.com/en/t/air-force-1-07-shoe-KyTDGepj/315122-111')
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, features="lxml")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nike uses the `redux.js` library for their store that creates a `JavaScript` variable that holds all the product information needed on a page. We can extract this variable using BeautifulSoup and then parse it as a `JSON` to easily query the content.

BeautifulSoup allows you to filter results with regular expressions. We can use this feature to find the `<script>` tag that holds the `redux.js` variable (it's called `INITIAL_REDUX_STATE`). We will use the `string` argument with a regex.

We will also use a session from `requests.Session` which is almost always recommended.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import json

url = 'https://www.nike.com/en/t/air-force-1-07-shoe-KyTDGepj/315122-111'

with requests.Session() as session:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(session.get(url).text, features="lxml")

script = soup.find("script", string=re.compile('INITIAL_REDUX_STATE')).string
redux = json.loads(script[script.find('{'):-1])
products = redux["Threads"]["products"]

for key, product in products.items():
    print('###', key)
    print(product)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you see the website, the data is loaded from the json in the script tag. All the data is inside the script tag. Hence, getting the data from script tag we get all the information.

The following script goes through each different product and prints all the different skus (different sizes) and the available skus.
You join on the `skuId` and get the sizes that are available

```
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://www.nike.com/en/t/air-force-1-07-shoe-KyTDGepj/315122-111')
res.raise_for_status()

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, features="lxml")
script = soup.find_all("script")
pdp_data = None
for i in script:
    if "INITIAL_REDUX_STATE" in i.text:
        pdp_data = i.text.strip()
        break

pdp_json_data = json.loads(pdp_data[pdp_data.index("{"):-1])

for prod, val in pdp_json_data["Threads"]["products"].items():
    print("Product ID - {}".format(prod))
    print("\nALL SKUS - \n")
    print(val["skus"])
    print("\nALL AVAILABLE SKUS \n")
    print(val["availableSkus"])
    print("----" * 10)
```

Output:

```
Product ID - 315122-111

ALL SKUS -

[{'id': '10042641', 'nikeSize': '6', 'skuId': '7d241ad9-39b0-54ad-ae85-e26ae377c2e2', 'localizedSize': 'M 6 / W 7.5', 'localizedSizePrefix': 'US'}, {'id': '10042642', 'nikeSize': '6.5', 'skuId': '63e00d84-b881-5b8f-9ebf-8ab8e8cd0fd5', 'localizedSize': 'M 6.5 / W 8', 'localizedSizePrefix': 'US'}, {'id': '10042643', 'nikeSize': '7', 'skuId': '630354e7-665d-5d75-9e56-114252ac5200', 'localizedSize': 'M 7 / W 8.5', 'localizedSizePrefix': 'US'}, {'id': '10042644', 'nikeSize': '7.5', 'skuId': '1293ec3b-12b2-581e-ade5-93ecb21df4e5', 'localizedSize': 'M 7.5 / W 9', 'localizedSizePrefix': 'US'}, {'id': '10042645', 'nikeSize': '8', 'skuId': 'ea426aaf-b890-57a5-a165-8af7282e58aa', 'localizedSize': 'M 8 / W 9.5', 'localizedSizePrefix': 'US'}, {'id': '10042646', 'nikeSize': '8.5', 'skuId': '292e8c22-943b-5b9d-8e40-0b754095c3fc', 'localizedSize': 'M 8.5 / W 10', 'localizedSizePrefix': 'US'}, {'id': '10042647', 'nikeSize': '9', 'skuId': '511db6fd-980d-5de8-9a28-7c5726a75dbe', 'localizedSize': 'M 9 / W 10.5', 'localizedSizePrefix': 'US'}, {'id': '10042648', 'nikeSize': '9.5', 'skuId': '3d389867-233b-5bd4-a043-2c28f71b2c22', 'localizedSize': 'M 9.5 / W 11', 'localizedSizePrefix': 'US'}, {'id': '10042649', 'nikeSize': '10', 'skuId': '7b93373e-11be-5234-abb7-127593e43d79', 'localizedSize': 'M 10 / W 11.5', 'localizedSizePrefix': 'US'}, {'id': '10042650', 'nikeSize': '10.5', 'skuId': '404cd86f-affb-592a-b786-14e4040d8833', 'localizedSize': 'M 10.5 / W 12', 'localizedSizePrefix': 'US'}, {'id': '10042651', 'nikeSize': '11', 'skuId': '38fd8eb6-a4bc-5a7e-9335-aaf3a37a62e8', 'localizedSize': 'M 11 / W 12.5', 'localizedSizePrefix': 'US'}, {'id': '10042652', 'nikeSize': '11.5', 'skuId': '0b289be2-7cf8-5371-a794-04704838b646', 'localizedSize': 'M 11.5 / W 13', 'localizedSizePrefix': 'US'}, {'id': '10042653', 'nikeSize': '12', 'skuId': 'eb42c0de-dab2-55da-a97d-a554ca06bec0', 'localizedSize': 'M 12 / W 13.5', 'localizedSizePrefix': 'US'}, {'id': '10042654', 'nikeSize': '12.5', 'skuId': '27292cf9-9c10-5bed-831a-47cc4a20bbd3', 'localizedSize': 'M 12.5 / W 14', 'localizedSizePrefix': 'US'}, {'id': '10042655', 'nikeSize': '13', 'skuId': '954dbd59-1274-5c42-b489-1419f418609a', 'localizedSize': 'M 13 / W 14.5', 'localizedSizePrefix': 'US'}]

ALL AVAILABLE SKUS

[{'id': '3d389867-233b-5bd4-a043-2c28f71b2c22', 'productId': '18c4b01b-5c4e-52d4-8fb0-25b5962745bd', 'resourceType': 'availableSkus', 'links': {'self': {'ref': '/deliver/available_skus/v1/3d389867-233b-5bd4-a043-2c28f71b2c22'}}, 'available': True, 'level': 'LOW', 'skuId': '3d389867-233b-5bd4-a043-2c28f71b2c22'}, {'id': '7b93373e-11be-5234-abb7-127593e43d79', 'productId': '18c4b01b-5c4e-52d4-8fb0-25b5962745bd', 'resourceType': 'availableSkus', 'links': {'self': {'ref': '/deliver/available_skus/v1/7b93373e-11be-5234-abb7-127593e43d79'}}, 'available': True, 'level': 'HIGH', 'skuId': '7b93373e-11be-5234-abb7-127593e43d79'}, {'id': '404cd86f-affb-592a-b786-14e4040d8833', 'productId': '18c4b01b-5c4e-52d4-8fb0-25b5962745bd', 'resourceType': 'availableSkus', 'links': {'self': {'ref': '/deliver/available_skus/v1/404cd86f-affb-592a-b786-14e4040d8833'}}, 'available': True, 'level': 'LOW', 'skuId': '404cd86f-affb-592a-b786-14e4040d8833'}, {'id': '38fd8eb6-a4bc-5a7e-9335-aaf3a37a62e8', 'productId': '18c4b01b-5c4e-52d4-8fb0-25b5962745bd', 'resourceType': 'availableSkus', 'links': {'self': {'ref': '/deliver/available_skus/v1/38fd8eb6-a4bc-5a7e-9335-aaf3a37a62e8'}}, 'available': True, 'level': 'HIGH', 'skuId': '38fd8eb6-a4bc-5a7e-9335-aaf3a37a62e8'}, {'id': 'eb42c0de-dab2-55da-a97d-a554ca06bec0', 'productId': '18c4b01b-5c4e-52d4-8fb0-25b5962745bd', 'resourceType': 'availableSkus', 'links': {'self': {'ref': '/deliver/available_skus/v1/eb42c0de-dab2-55da-a97d-a554ca06bec0'}}, 'available': True, 'level': 'LOW', 'skuId': 'eb42c0de-dab2-55da-a97d-a554ca06bec0'}, {'id': '954dbd59-1274-5c42-b489-1419f418609a', 'productId': '18c4b01b-5c4e-52d4-8fb0-25b5962745bd', 'resourceType': 'availableSkus', 'links': {'self': {'ref': '/deliver/available_skus/v1/954dbd59-1274-5c42-b489-1419f418609a'}}, 'available': True, 'level': 'LOW', 'skuId': '954dbd59-1274-5c42-b489-1419f418609a'}]
----------------------------------------
Product ID - 315122-001

ALL SKUS -

[{'id': '10042620', 'nikeSize': '6', 'skuId': 'cabe18cd-9b75-541b-a07f-48706a84a6e9', 'localizedSize': '6', 'localizedSizePrefix': 'US'}, {'id': '10042621', 'nikeSize': '6.5', 'skuId': 'f20f4e19-1eb5-598d-b695-2aa9c83f9348', 'localizedSize': '6.5', 'localizedSizePrefix': 'US'}, {'id': '10042622', 'nikeSize': '7', 'skuId': 'de2ce766-2956-514b-ae13-263dc970792a', 'localizedSize': '7', 'localizedSizePrefix': 'US'}, {'id': '10042623', 'nikeSize': '7.5', 'skuId': 'c894d6e4-fa3c-536f-ad68-593c8e53830c', 'localizedSize': '7.5', 'localizedSizePrefix': 'US'}, {'id': '10042624', 'nikeSize': '8', 'skuId': '3d60ee94-5b49-5109-8328-f681fd1569e3', 'localizedSize': '8', 'localizedSizePrefix': 'US'}, {'id': '10042625', 'nikeSize': '8.5', 'skuId': '4bb0e8fb-d3e7-545b-a4f1-f947f37a2023', 'localizedSize': '8.5', 'localizedSizePrefix': 'US'}, {'id': '10042626', 'nikeSize': '9', 'skuId': '176c9987-34e3-564a-8aee-8f4f7d917191', 'localizedSize': '9', 'localizedSizePrefix': 'US'}, {'id': '10042627', 'nikeSize': '9.5', 'skuId': '9c0e4e0d-155d-5344-8275-41a5c046e873', 'localizedSize': '9.5', 'localizedSizePrefix': 'US'}, {'id': '10042628', 'nikeSize': '10', 'skuId': '12cc5f10-1295-5160-944b-6dc97ce3fb53', 'localizedSize': '10', 'localizedSizePrefix': 'US'}, {'id': '10042629', 'nikeSize': '10.5', 'skuId': '89e450e5-02bb-5598-8cee-8c21028ccd76', 'localizedSize': '10.5', 'localizedSizePrefix': 'US'}, {'id': '10042630', 'nikeSize': '11', 'skuId': '76d0c8d7-487e-561e-ad6d-cc3c233c1b5e', 'localizedSize': '11', 'localizedSizePrefix': 'US'}, {'id': '10042631', 'nikeSize': '11.5', 'skuId': '7970a1c0-e075-5485-8fd7-96d0d23959df', 'localizedSize': '11.5', 'localizedSizePrefix': 'US'}, {'id': '10042632', 'nikeSize': '12', 'skuId': 'b8a04e7a-6e0e-5032-b301-03ed1f824aa4', 'localizedSize': '12', 'localizedSizePrefix': 'US'}, {'id': '10042634', 'nikeSize': '13', 'skuId': 'c8f6e4a0-46e8-5f7a-8934-9fdab04e3250', 'localizedSize': '13', 'localizedSizePrefix': 'US'}]

ALL AVAILABLE SKUS

[]
----------------------------------------
```